# ImportError: DLL load failed when running a script tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, importerror

I created a multiprocessing script that runs perfectly when running in an IDE (Spyder) but is giving me errors when running through the script tool in ArcGIS Pro.

Here is the traceback:

```
Running script Script...
Failed script Script...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<user>\ArcGIS\Projects\K_L1\K_L1.tbx#ScriptTool_KL1.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\<user>\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone13\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\<user>\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone13\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to execute (ScriptTool).
```

The IDE was downloaded directly from Pro, and works fine. I have searched on google, but nothing popped up that was related to using ArcGIS Pro, only running in IDEs.

Comment: When you run it from Spyder, is Spyder using Pro's version of Python? If not, the error implies you have something installed in your dev environment that doesn't exist in the Pro-Python-Conda environment.